# Unity 3D Undoes changes that I've made

Tags: unity-game-engine, savechanges, autosave

I'm a newcomer to Unity3D development, and, while following a tutorial to make my first game, I  noticed that a few steps I kept repeating as I flipped between the Unity application and my browser (chrome), which were both in full screen, certain steps that I had made would occasionally be reversed when I returned.

The two times I noticed it happening, GUISkins and Scripts that I'd added to game objects had been removed.

Has anyone had a similar problem? To prevent this, do I save the scene or the project? Does Unity offer some sort of Autosave function?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you making changes while in play mode? These changes do not stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes made to the scene while the game is in play mode will not persist. Once you get out of the play mode, the changes made will be reverted.

Comment: Thanks Varaquilex, I guess I assumed I wouldn't have any issues if I paused play mode!